# Sass can't compile using webstorm

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, webstorm

When I want to use Sass in the Webstorm IDE it seems to be using Ruby 1.8 (OS Default) rather than my RVM Ruby Version (1.9.x).

Now I can set the path for Sass in the Watcher-Configuration:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

However then the next thing I run into is that other dependencies aren't found:

```
env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory
```

How can I configure WebStorm or my Mac, that it completely ignores the Builtin Ruby and always uses RVM (not just in the Terminal.app)

Comment: Run WebStorm from the Terminal: `open -a /Applications/WebStorm.app/` or make the file watcher task environment identical to the one you have in Terminal which is [not so by default](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891). See also the [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15764459/104891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of providing the `compass` command with `watch` parameter, provide a `bash` command with `–login -c "compass compile"` parameter.

More info here: [How to use compass in phpstorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806938/how-to-use-compass-in-phpstorm/15810163#15810163)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the environment variable that worked for me:

```
Name: PATH

Value: /Users/peteshau/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/peteshau/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin
```

I needed both of those values.