# phpstorm - scss file watcher issue

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I am trying to setup phpstorm filewatcher in order to precompile my .scss, and I have the following error message :

```
"C:/Program Files/Ruby193/Ruby193/bin/compass.bat" --no-cache --update style.scss:style.css
'"ruby.exe"' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, 
    un programme executable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Which translates in english to something like :

```
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognised as an internal or external command, 
    executable program or command file.
```

-I looked into this question, but it did not solve my problem : [PhpStorm: SCSS File Watcher Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760140/phpstorm-scss-file-watcher-settings)

-Here is a screenshot of my settings.
[image: Php storm watcher settings]

Thks.

Comment: "ruby.exe" cannot be found when `compass.bat` is launched from PhpStorm. 1) Try restarting your computer (so PATH variable will be properly updated) 2) Alter `compass.bat` and specify FULL PATH to ruby.exe

Comment: For the "program" path, I had already tried scss.bat and compass.bat and I had the same error message.  To change it to ruby.exe does not seem to work (and I don't think it's a solution since I want to process .scss files, not launch ruby).  I changed the image of the settings with scss.bat in the program path.

Comment: For the "environment variables", to change it to ".../bin/ruby.exe" instead of ".../bin/" did not solve the problem.  Concerning the "PATH variable" you are talking about, which path variable are you talking about?  thks.

Comment: What "PATH variable"? -- standard one: open console (cmd.exe) and type `PATH` and enter. Or via GUI -- `My Computer | Right Click | Properties` or the same via `Control Panel | System`. Then `Advanced System Settings | Environment variables button`

Comment: By *"specify FULL PATH to ruby.exe"* I meant not changing path in File Watcher .. but editing actual `compass.bat` file and providing full path to ruby.exe there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words. Here is how you should set it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two problems. One is that Ruby is set up in a very improper fashion, you have `Ruby193/Ruby193`, which perhaps poses a problem. Another problem is that you've changed your environment variables. Keep it empty and see if it works, it works fine for me, so I guess if there is any problem, its with your Ruby setup.

Another potential problems is that your PATH might not be set up right to match with Ruby, so double-check your path.