# PHPStorm: Missing file for SCSS configuration?

Tags: ruby, sass, config, phpstorm

I'm trying to switch over to PHPStorm and I would like to activate the transpiling of SCSS files, but it seems like one file is missing in my ruby-folder.

I found an image in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748810/phpstorm-scss-file-watcher-issue), which shows how to configure the file watcher:
[image: File Watcher configuration]

The problem is now that I don't have a "scss.bat" in my /bin/-folder, to insert in the "Program:"-field. I made sure that I have the latest version of ruby by downloading it from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

These ".bat"-files are in my folder:

- erb
- gem
- irb
- rake
- rdoc
- ri
- setrbvars
- testrb

I tried every file, but I get a different error each time.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error:

I forgot to install SCSS after my Ruby-installation. To do so open your commandline and type:

```
gem install scss
```