# PhpStorm File Watcher for SCSS stopped working

Tags: sass, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, file-watcher

The File Watcher suddenly stopped working and producing the error below:

`Automatic upload: check for related changes from File Watchers took too much time and was cancelled.`

Here's my watcher settings:
[image]

The full Arguments field value: `--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

I tried the solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748810/phpstorm-scss-file-watcher-issue) but still generated the same error.
[image]

I'm not sure what did I miss. For I've been using PHPStorm for several months and didn't encounter error like this. Seems the File Watchers SCSS and SASS aren't working anymore .I tried resetting the phpstorm each time I apply changes.

Comment: Something weird might be going on with SCSS & Ruby. Have you tried to run the SCSS compile command manually, does this take a long time to complete too?

Comment: Click "Create output file from stdout" to see if there's anything worthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

I just installed the latest version of Phpstorm (2016.2) with all new settings and config. The Sass File Watcher are now working perfectly.